# Three.js Remove background before image loading

Tags: canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

I am looking into this code

```
window.onload = init;
....
```

Reference
https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/PNXbGo

Before the animation starts, when the images are not loaded, it shows black background. 
I have tried a lot but not able to change the color of it or remove it.

Any help or suggestion to how to change color to white or transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two image loaders in that fiddle... the function parameter is called when each image is fully loaded... you can check a counter in those functions and when it reaches 2, then call a routine to start the rest of the app.

```
as in the following codepen:
```

https://codepen.io/manthrax/pen/wQwPKo

Comment: Why not use `THREE.LoadingManager()` for the purpose to run the render loop when all the resources are loaded?

Comment: Sure! I just went for the quickest answer that would get OP going.. feel free to expand on adding a loading manager..